# Exception in IEnumerable when it's null

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a method returning `IEnumerable` object, but I found that sometimes (on error) the method returns null value of `IEnumerable`.

The method looks something like this.

```
IEnumerable<string> function(String param1, String param2)
{
    IEnumerable s = null;

    s = (some query over here);

    return s;
}
```

When I call this method with `param2`, the function internally fails and returns s which is null at this time.

So, to detect this I used,

```
 IEnumerable<string> a = function(1,0);
 if (a.count<string> > 0) //not working
 if (a == 0)  //not working.
```

What is the correct method to use `IEnumerable` and check whether it is null before any other operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours `s = (some query over here);` is returning null. That is why you are getting the exception.

Later your check should be:

```
if(a != null)
```

and

```
if(a.Count() > 0)
```

You can combine both as:

```
if(a!=null && a.Count() >0)
{
 // do your work
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. My laziness..checking it with 0. Yes, It should be something like u suggested

Answer (score 3):

you could return an empty enumerable if the search result was null:

```
IEnumerable<string> function(String param1, String param2)
  {
         IEnumerable s = null;

         s = (some query over here);

         return s ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Dice. I am a newbie to C#. This taught me about the operator "??". (If s is null, return an empty enumerator. Else, return its original value.) It helped.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not the same as an enumeration without any elements. Therefore, your check for `if(a.count<string> > 0)` fails. (In fact, `a` isn't pointing to any instance whose number of elements you could retrieve with `Count`.)

Also, `null` is not the same as the integer value `0`. Therefore, your check for `if(a == 0)` fails, too.

However, `null` is a keyword in C# and you can compare to that:

```
if (a == null)
```

Comment: Thanks OR Mapper. It helps. +1 for "null is not the same as an enumeration without any elements"